# open port with ip-adress

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ip, port

i want to get access to my server from network.

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

how do i change/add/replace this to:

```
tcp        ?      ? my_ip:80                ??????                  LISTEN
```

and what are the numbers i tagged with "?" for?

Comment: You want to listen to your ipv4 address?

Comment: yes that is correct,so that i can get access to my website from network for testing

Comment: Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106502/apache2-does-not-run-on-ipv4-tcp-port if that `Listen 0.0.0.0:80` helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ports are opened by processes, so your service needs to be configured to open the port in question on the interface/protocol required. In your case, you want to change the interface to 0.0.0.0 or your LAN IP, and the protocol to TCP4.

you will have to do this in your webservers config file. without knowing your exact HTTP server, we can't tell more, but most linux servers allow you to specify what Interface to bind to, and sometimes what TCP/IP version to use. either way, if you bind to an interface by IPv4 address, that usually creates an TCP4 listener.

Comment: i really don't understand why,without changing anything, but know it works.